# PyQgis Cycle to create multiple maps

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, mapping

I am developing a PyQgis script, which automates the creation of maps in .png format. Loading the corresponding rasters and shapes first, adding format to each layer and then creating a template and saving the map. Finally delete the layers and the template.

The program is organized in functions:
1: addlayers ()
2: format ()
3: zoomtolayer ()
4: printlayer ()
5: clean ()

At the end of each function I add a QTimer to call the next function and wait for Qgis to finish rendering what was done in the previous function. As the following line:

```
QTimer.singleShot(1000, format)
```

This works very well when I only enter a single group of layers to create 1 map (Each map consists of 2 Raster, 2 Shapes).

But when I create a cycle to run the functions several times and load the layers of a list (4 by 4). The program conflicts and what it does is load all the layers in the list and add format only to the last layer.

I've tried several things, like adding time.sleep () to stop the program in which Qgis renders the maps, however, it only delays the program and then the same thing happens above.

The most recent attempt was to create an infinite cycle that searches if the file to be created exists, stopping the program at that point until the image is saved. But what happened was that the program loaded the first layers of the list and was stuck in the cycle, without even going to the second function.

Because the program works well when I enter only a group of layers, I think the problem is in the following part of the code:

```
list=[k for k in range(len(list_parcelas))]
for n in list:

    dir_pozo=list_pozo[n]
    dir_raster=list_raster[n]
    dir_parcelas=list_parcelas[n]

    addlayers(dir_pozo,dir_raster,dir_parcelas)

    while os.path.isfile(dir_raster[0:52]+dir_raster[124:-5]+'.png')==False:
        print('...')
```

In the code above I have defined the lists of the layers that I am going to use, which are three: list_pozo, list_raster, list_parcelas. and the fourth layer is that of google satellite.

With these defined lists I create a list of the amount of maps that I am going to create and then start the cycle to read each group of layers. I keep and command call the first function addlayers and then I create the infinite cycle that as I said does not work

This is my complete code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import os


def addlayers(dir_pozo,dir_parcelas,dir_raster):

    #Agregar open street map (u otros similares)
    url_O='type=xyz&url=http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs%3Ds@189%26gl%3Dcn%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0'
    Olayer=QgsRasterLayer(url_O,'GSatelite','wms')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(Olayer)

    #Abrir Raster, Parcelas, Pozo
    rlayer=iface.addRasterLayer(dir_raster, "ETr (mm)")

    path_to_ports_layer = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "data", "ports", dir_parcelas)
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_ports_layer, "Parcelas", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

    path_to_ports_layer_pozos = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "data", "ports", dir_pozo)
    player = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_ports_layer_pozos, "Pozo", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(player)

    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, formatos)

def formatos():

    player=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
    vlayer=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[1]
    rlayer=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[2]

    #Formato Pozo ------------------------------------------
    player.renderer().symbol().setColor(QColor('#00fe08'))

    layer=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
    layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    background_color = QgsTextBackgroundSettings()

    background_color.setFillColor(QColor('#bff2ac'))
    background_color.setEnabled(True)

    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(12)
    text_format.setBackground(background_color)

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))

    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    layer_settings.fieldName = "Name"
    layer_settings.placement = 0

    layer_settings.enabled = True

    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.triggerRepaint()

    #Formato Raster ----------------------------------------
    rrender=rlayer.renderer()
    rprovider=rlayer.dataProvider()
    rextent=rlayer.extent()
    rver= rprovider.hasStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All)

    rstats=rprovider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, rextent, 0)

    min=rstats.minimumValue
    max=rstats.maximumValue
    range=max-min
    add=range/4
    interval_1=min+add
    interval_2=min+(2*add)
    interval_3=min+(3*add)

    colDic={'C1':'#d7191c','C2':'#fdae61',\
            'C3':'#ffffbf','C4':'#abd9e9','C5':'#2c7bb6'}

    valueList=[min, interval_1,interval_2,interval_3, max]

    valList=[]
    for m in valueList:
        valList.append('{0:.2f}'.format(m))

    lst=[QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0], QColor(colDic['C1']), f'{valList[0]}'),\
         QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1], QColor(colDic['C2']), f'{valList[1]}'),\
         QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2], QColor(colDic['C3']), f'{valList[2]}'),\
         QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[3], QColor(colDic['C4']), f'{valList[3]}'),\
         QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[4], QColor(colDic['C5']), f'{valList[4]}')]

    myRasterShader= QgsRasterShader()
    myColorRamp= QgsColorRampShader()

    myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(lst)
    myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
    myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

    myPseudoRender= QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(),
                                                     rlayer.type(),
                                                     myRasterShader)

    rlayer.setRenderer(myPseudoRender)
    rlayer.triggerRepaint()

    #Formato Parcelas ------------------------------------------
    registry=QgsApplication.symbolLayerRegistry()
    linemeta=registry.symbolLayerMetadata('SimpleLine')

    symbol=QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType())

    #Line layer
    linelayer=linemeta.createSymbolLayer({'width':'0.26','color':'#1f78b4','offset':'0','penstyle':'solid','use_custom_dash':'0','joinstyle':'bevel','capstyle':'square'})

    #Replace the default layer with our two custom layers
    symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
    symbol.appendSymbolLayer(linelayer)
    #symbol.appendSymbolLayer(markerLayer)

    #Replace the renderer of the current layer
    renderer=QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)
    vlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, zoomtolayer)

def zoomtolayer():

    #Zoom
    extent = QgsRectangle()
    extent.setMinimal()
    layers_z = [iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0], iface.mapCanvas().layers()[2]]

    for layer_z in layers_z:
        extent.combineExtentWith(layer_z.extent())

    extent.scale(1.5) # Increase a bit the extent to make sure all geometries lie inside 
    iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(extent)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, imprimirlayer)

def imprimirlayer():

    project=QgsProject.instance()
    manager=project.layoutManager()
    layout=QgsPrintLayout(project)
    layoutName="PrintLayout"

    layout.initializeDefaults()

    layout.setName(layoutName)
    manager.addLayout(layout)

    #Adding a map
    map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
    map.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)

    #Set Map Extent
    #defines map extent using layer extent
    def extencion():
        #Zoom
        extent = QgsRectangle()
        extent.setMinimal()
        layers_z = [iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0], iface.mapCanvas().layers()[2]]

        for layer_z in layers_z:
            extent.combineExtentWith(layer_z.extent())

        extent.scale(2.5)
        return extent

    extent=extencion()
    map.setExtent(extent)
    layout.addLayoutItem(map)

    #Grid format
    map.grid().setEnabled(True)
    map.grid().setStyle(1)
    map.grid().setIntervalX(500)  
    map.grid().setIntervalY(500)  
    map.grid().setAnnotationEnabled(True) 
    map.grid().setGridLineColor(QColor('White'))  
    map.grid().setGridLineWidth(0.3)
    map.grid().setAnnotationPrecision(0)  
    map.grid().setAnnotationFrameDistance(1)  
    map.grid().setAnnotationFontColor(QColor('White')) 
    map.grid().setAnnotationDisplay(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.HideAll, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Right)
    map.grid().setAnnotationDisplay(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.HideAll, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Top)
    map.grid().setAnnotationPosition(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.InsideMapFrame, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Bottom)
    map.grid().setAnnotationDirection(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Horizontal, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Bottom)
    map.grid().setAnnotationPosition(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.InsideMapFrame, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Left)
    map.grid().setAnnotationDirection(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Vertical, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Left)

    #add legend 
    l = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
    for layout in l.printLayouts():    
        legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
        root = QgsLayerTree()
        for lyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
            if lyr.name() in ['ETr (mm)']:  
                root.addLayer(lyr)
            legend.model().setRootGroup(root)
            layout.addItem(legend)

    #add scale bar
    scalebar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout)
    scalebar.setStyle('Double Box') # optionally modify the style
    scalebar.setLinkedMap(map) # map is an instance of QgsLayoutItemMap
    scalebar.applyDefaultSize()
    layout.addItem(scalebar)

    #add north arrow
    northarr=QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
    northarr.setPicturePath('/usr/share/qgis/svg/arrows/NorthArrow_02.svg')
    northarr.setFixedSize(QgsLayoutSize(25,25))
    layout.addItem(northarr)

    #add labels title
    label_1 = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    label_1.setText("Análisis de Evapotranspiración")
    label_1.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
    label_1.adjustSizeToText()
    label_1.setFontColor(QColor('White'))
    layout.addItem(label_1)

    label_2 = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    label_2.setText("Asociado al Pozo:")
    label_2.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
    label_2.adjustSizeToText()
    label_2.setFontColor(QColor('White'))
    layout.addItem(label_2)

    label_3 = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    label_3.setText(dir_raster[136:-5])
    label_3.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
    label_3.adjustSizeToText()
    label_3.setFontColor(QColor('White'))
    layout.addItem(label_3)

    label_4 = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    label_4.setText(dir_raster[127:131]+'/'+dir_raster[131:133]+'/'+dir_raster[133:135])
    label_4.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
    label_4.adjustSizeToText()
    label_4.setFontColor(QColor('White'))
    layout.addItem(label_4)

    #Move & Resize map on print layout canvas
    map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(0, 0, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(297, 210, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

    legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(255, 130, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

    scalebar.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(250, 185, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

    northarr.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(20, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

    label_1.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 165, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    label_2.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 173, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    label_3.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(50, 181, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    label_4.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(50, 189, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))


    #Export the image
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    exporter.exportToImage(dir_raster[0:52]+dir_raster[124:-5]+'.png', QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())

    QTimer.singleShot(3000,limpiar)

def limpiar():

    player=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
    vlayer=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[1]
    rlayer=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[2]
    glayer=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[3]

    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(player)
    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(vlayer)
    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(rlayer)
    QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(glayer)

    project=QgsProject.instance()
    manager=project.layoutManager()
    layout_list=manager.printLayouts()

    for layout in layout_list:
        if layout.name()=='PrintLayout':
            manager.removeLayout(layout)


    print('Ya Termine =)')

#comienza el programa /////////////////////////////////////////////
carpetas=r'/home/alejandro/Escritorio/Proyecto Lerma/Pruebas/l' 
carpeta=os.listdir(carpetas)


list_pozo=[]
list_raster=[]
list_parcelas=[]
#Contador para las carpetas de los pozos
for i in carpeta:

    if '.' in i:
        continue

    archivos=os.listdir(carpetas+'/'+i)
    #Contador para las carpetas de las imagenes
    for x in archivos:
        if '.shp' in x:
            if 'pozo' in x:
                dir_pozo=x
            else:
                dir_parcelas=x

    dir_pozo=carpetas+'/'+i+'/'+dir_pozo
    dir_parcelas=carpetas+'/'+i+'/'+dir_parcelas
    for x in archivos:

        if '.' in x:
            continue

        archivos_2=os.listdir(carpetas+'/'+i+'/'+x)
        for y in archivos_2:

            if 'ET' in y:
                if '.xml' in y:
                    continue
                else:
                    dir_raster=y

        dir_raster=carpetas+'/'+i+'/'+x+'/'+dir_raster

        list_pozo.append(dir_pozo)
        list_raster.append(dir_raster)
        list_parcelas.append(dir_parcelas)

lista=[k for k in range(len(list_parcelas))]
for n in lista:

    dir_pozo=list_pozo[n]
    dir_raster=list_raster[n]
    dir_parcelas=list_parcelas[n]

    addlayers(dir_pozo,dir_raster,dir_parcelas)

    while os.path.isfile(dir_raster[0:52]+dir_raster[124:-5]+'.png')==False:
        print('...')



#dir_pozo='/home/alejandro/Escritorio/Proyecto Lerma/Pruebas/pozos_chap/01-San Nicolas Peralta/pozo.shp'
#dir_parcelas='/home/alejandro/Escritorio/Proyecto Lerma/Pruebas/pozos_chap/01-San Nicolas Peralta/PR 01.shp'
#dir_raster='/home/alejandro/Escritorio/Proyecto Lerma/Pruebas/pozos_chap/01-San Nicolas Peralta/LC08_L1TP_026047_20190926_20191017_01_T1_cut_cut/ET_20190926_01-San Nicolas Peralta.tiff'

#addlayers(dir_pozo,dir_parcelas,dir_raster)
```

Comment: What happens if you call the next function like formatos() instead of using the QTimer statement?

Comment: Hi @artwork21, just load the layers and does not apply the format